# Как определить, какой скрипт выполняется?

Tags: perl, linux

Периодически в top'е вижу грузящий машину perl. Как определить текст выполняемого скрипта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `top` нажмите клавишу «`c`» — если процесс не менял свой cmdline, то увидите все детали (вместо `perl` будет полное `/usr/bin/perl foo.pl`)

Как правило этого должно быть достаточно. Но если нужны подробности (например у вас десяток `foo.pl` в разных директориях), то запомните PID процесса и посмотрите, например, `ls -lad /proc/$PID/cwd` (текущий каталог процесса) или `cat /proc/$PID/environ | tr '\0' '\n'` (переменные окружения).

Или, как еще вариант, поставьте [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) как удобную интерактивную альтернативу `top`'у. Спрашивайте в пакетах вашего дистрибутива.